# redirect to SSL works but get variables don't work

Tags: curl, nginx, ssl

I have nginx and in server section and port 80 I redirect my host to port 443 such as:

```
server {
   location / {
       return 307 https://$host$request_uri/?lang=fa
   }
}
```

It's work and redirect to SSL, But when I put location in SSL block, I get recursively such as :

```
https://mydomain//?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa/?lang=fa
```

I need to set my `https` to `https://mydomain/?lang=fa` I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variables are working just fine. The problem is, you are adding essentially only the URL query string part, so the URI path part will remain the same: the `location /` will also match after the redirect (and merging the consecutive slashes), and so you'll get an infinite recursion.

This is because the URL specification says the order of query string arguments should not matter, i.e. a request for `https://mydomain/?lang=fa&foo=bar` should be treated the same as a request for `https://mydomain/?foo=bar&lang=fa`.

The nginx `location` will match the URI path part only. See [this question at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/811981/442837):

> **Question:** Can nginx location blocks match a URL query string?
>
> **Short answer:** No.

Documentation reference: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Without knowing what you actually want to do to the request after the `?lang=fa` part is added, it's hard to give a working example.

Comment: I deleted location block and after block I redirected but, I get the infinite loop.